# Failed audit on question which doesn't seem programming-related

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed an audit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27268462), and I don't understand why.

It doesn't seem to fall under any of the categories listed in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

- **a specific programming problem**: No.
- **a software algorithm**: No.
- **software tools commonly used by programmers**: Programmers use web browsers, computers, and YouTube, but it's safe to say that isn't enough for it be on-topic.
- **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**: No.

Conclusion: No?

Upon reading that question, the first answer that popped into my mind was "Get an ad-blocking app/extension which allows you to block certain page elements", and not anything which involves programming.

There is only one tag, `[youtube]`, whose description says:

> YouTube is a video-sharing website on which users can upload, share, and view videos. StackOverflow questions tagged with "youtube" should be about specific programming problems, software tools, or libraries. If your question is about the YouTube API, the "youtube-api" tag should also be added.

The question doesn't fit *that* description either.

Even if it were to be tweaked such that it is slightly more on-topic, and those changes would likely be to bring it more in line with the *answers*, I think it would still be a poor question since it would then amount to little more than "write a program for me".

What am I missing here, I am going crazy?

Comment: Personally, I think it is programming related.  However, I also think it is too broad and is asking for answers that solve the whole thing for them.  So I would have voted to close as too broad.

Comment: @Taplar _Personally, I think it is programming related._ How come? Can you elaborate?

Comment: They are asking how it can be disabled.  That could potentialy be done with a userscript.  Userscripts are programming related.

Comment: @Taplar Sure, *potentially*. As I wrote in my post, however, they make no mention of that, and it isn't the first thing which came to mind.

Comment: @Taplar Can be solved with programming != programming problem. I could ask how to open my web browser if I don't have a shortcut on my desktop, sure it can be solved with programming, it's still not a programming problem

Comment: Lots of general computing problems can be solved by writing a script, though. Does that make them on-topic? And as you say, even if it were edited to specifically ask for how to write a script that does that, it would still be close-worthy anyway.

Comment: Yeah you definitely shouldn't have failed that. The question isn't a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 6):

> I just failed an audit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27268462), and I don't understand why.

Because at the time you were audited, the question wasn't closed, and thus the automatic audit system assumed that the community agrees it is an acceptable question.

Comment: Right, that part I understood, I was simply wondering whether or not it is an acceptable question. It had a score of +11 at the time, so I was doubting myself. I should have made my post here clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the question being closed, and don't understand why you failed that audit

As [Taplar's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401671/failed-audit-on-question-which-doesnt-seem-programming-related#comment799511_401671) says,

> They are asking how it can be disabled. That could potentialy be done with a userscript. Userscripts are programming related.

Sure, that is technically programming related, but in their question they aren't mentioning anything about a user script. In this case, since they haven't done any research and haven't tried anything, I would probably flag <sub>or close for 3k</sub> as Needs Details or Clarity.

And anyways, things that can be done with programming aren't always on topic, as [Nick suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401671/failed-audit-on-question-which-doesnt-seem-programming-related#comment799514_401671).

In any case, I don't understand why you failed the review audit, unless you selected a different close reason than the one on the post currently.

---

[Never Mind](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401671/failed-audit-on-question-which-doesnt-seem-programming-related/401678?noredirect=1#comment799541_401678), as Alexei Levenkov said the question was closed *after* the audit. So it does make sense that you failed the audit, but doesn't make sense why the question stayed open.

Comment: You should look at the timeline - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63680896/timeline and adjust the answer... I totally agree that it is unclear why question stayed open (causing OP to fail audit), but it is obvious why OP failed the audit - they *correctly* VTC on the question which *incorrectly* stayed open without close/down votes.